# Mount NTFS disk in Windows 7 formatted in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, mount, drive-letter

[image]

I want to mount / assign a drive letter to the highlighted disk above, but that option is not available. The disk is formatted as NTFS in Ubuntu and contains around 1 TB data. How can I mount it in Windows 7?

This is the menu I get when I right click on the partition:
[image]

**Diskpart**

```
C:\Windows\system32>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: WORKSTATION

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online           74 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online         1863 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    Online          119 GB  1024 KB

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> detail disk

ST2000DL003-9VT166 ATA Device
Disk ID: 9A4CC02A
Type   : ATA
Status : Online
Path   : 1
Target : 1
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1100)#ATA(C01T01L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

There are no volumes.
```

Comment: Right click the disk (lower section - within the white space as shown in your diagram) and there should be an option "Change drive letter and paths"?

Comment: @BigChris that option is not available (greyed out)

Comment: @Znarkus - The drive has zero data on it.  The best option would be to format the drive through Windows.  While NTFS support through Linux is stable it does not fully implement the NTFS specifications.

Comment: @Ramhound It looks like that in the screenshot, but the drive actually contains 1 TB of data. I formatted the partition in Ubuntu with `mkfs.ntfs --quick` and copied 1 TB worth of files with `cp -pr`.

Comment: I'm unsure of what switches you may need to use but Windows 7's `DISKPART` may be able to help...

Comment: @Znarkus - What version of Ubuntu. exactly?  Because at this point in time it has no filesystem Windows detects.

Comment: @Ramhound Ubuntu 13.04. NTFS-3G was released as stable in 2007.

Comment: @Znarkus - **Yes...I know that, I even said that myself...**. It does not mean it implements the entire NTFS specification. **All I know ( besides the obvious fact NTFS-3G is stable ) is your screenshot shows no filesystem, and your disk as being 100% empty.

Comment: Ramhound is right. If a non-Windows-readable partition was on the disk, Windows would show it as still taking up space... I think you may have to go back to Ubuntu, back up your disk and then format it in Windows and restore the files... a big job but we're running out of options

Answer (score 0):

1. Open an elevated command prompt
2. Type in `diskpart`
3. Type `list disk` to see a list of disks
4. Type `select disk #`  (where # is the disk you want)
5. Type `detail disk` to see partitions
6. Type `select volume #`  (where # is the volume you want)
7. Type `assign letter=x`  (where x is the drive letter)
8. Exit diskpart
9. Check `Disk Management` to see if your volume now has a letter

Comment: Thanks. "There are no volumes." on step 5. Added the transcript to the question.